# Amazon Linux cannot access nginx on port 80

Tags: linux, nginx, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami

I have installed `nginx` on my AMI by `yum`

```
sudo yum install nginx
```

And then, I open all port in my AMI `security group`

`All traffic - All - All - 0.0.0.0/0`

And then, I start `nginx` by command

```
sudo service nginx start
```

And then, I access my `nginx` web service by `http://public-ip`
but I cannot access by this way.

I try to check the connection in my server.

```
ssh my_account@my_ip
```

And then,

```
wget http://localhost -O-
```

And It worked fine.

I cannot figure out what is the root cause, and then I change `nginx` port from `80` to `8081` and I restart the `nginx` server.

And then, I try to access again. It worked fine. WTH...

```
http://public-ip:8081
```

I don't know exactly what is going on?

Could you tell me what is the problem.

Comment: Based on what you've said, gremlins. However what's most likely is a very small mistake you've made. There's no way to help with the information you've provided, you'll need to go through things step by step to work out the problem. That or pay someone to do it for you.

Comment: Amazon Linux or RedHat/Centos or ... ?